# GitHub Enterprise Self-Hosted Runner unable to fetch LFS files

Tags: ubuntu, github, github-actions

I've recently gotten access to an instance of the self-hosted enterprise GitHub and have been tasked with getting a runner working for some eventual CI/CD work. GitHub is on version 3.8 and I have a self-hosted runner on an ubuntu 20.04 LTS instance. I've successfully gotten the runner installed and connected. I can clone/checkout repositories using the action/checkout@v3 method. However, I'm unable to use the lfs flag for that command. I end up receiving "LFS: Client error:  *filepath*" and "Error: error: failed to fetch some objects from 'myrepo/info/lfs'"

The repository checks out fine but of course none of the lfs files have been fetched. I've tried a few things to try and figure out what's going on, but with no luck. The only method I've found that actually works is to run the workflow and have it checkout (without the lfs flag) and then navigate to the checked out repo and run a git lfs fetch from the terminal. It prompts me for a username and password (I provide it my username and an access token) and it fetches the lfs files. From then on, I can enable the lfs flag with no errors.

I have tried providing the same token via the 'token' flag for the checkout action, but I get the same error as if I didn't give it the token. It seems to me like there's an authentication issue, but I'm not entirely sure why or what. I could also be completely off base and am just confused. Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)